# How to get specific object from ModelNode result

Tags: java, jboss, wildfly, application-server

I work with *ModelControllerClient* to get some information about the Logger which are used at the *Wildfly server*.
I would like to have a list of all logger names.

This is how I get all informations about the logger:

```
ModelNode op = new ModelNode();
op.get("operation").set("read-resource");

ModelNode address = op.get("address");
address.add("subsystem", "logging");
address.add("logger", "*");

ModelNode result = client.execute(op);
```

This is a litte example of the *ModelNode* result I get.

```
{
        "address" => [
            ("subsystem" => "logging"),
            ("logger" => "jacorb")
        ],
        "outcome" => "success",
        "result" => {
            "category" => "jacorb",
            "filter" => undefined,
            "filter-spec" => undefined,
            "handlers" => undefined,
            "level" => "WARN",
            "use-parent-handlers" => true
        }
    },
    {
        "address" => [
            ("subsystem" => "logging"),
            ("logger" => "jacorb.config")
        ],
        "outcome" => "success",
        "result" => {
            "category" => "jacorb.config",
            "filter" => undefined,
            "filter-spec" => undefined,
            "handlers" => undefined,
            "level" => "ERROR",
            "use-parent-handlers" => true
        }
    },
```

I would just like to get the values of "logger" / "category".

I tried to get the name of the loggers with:

```
result.get("logger");
```

but it returned "undefined". I guess the problem is that I have more than one object called "logger". The same happens when I try it with "category".

Comment: Did you check https://developer.jboss.org/thread/275166 thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to first read the result. In the simple case it would be `result.get("result", "logger")`. You could also use the `Operations` API and do something like `Operations.readResult(result).get("logger")`.

If you want just the logger names here's an example:

```java
try (ModelControllerClient client = ModelControllerClient.Factory.create("localhost", 9990)) {
    final ModelNode address = Operations.createAddress("subsystem", "logging");
    final ModelNode op = Operations.createOperation(ClientConstants.READ_CHILDREN_NAMES_OPERATION, address);
    op.get(ClientConstants.CHILD_TYPE).set("logger");
    final ModelNode result = client.execute(op);
    if (Operations.isSuccessfulOutcome(result)) {
        final List<ModelNode> loggerNames = Operations.readResult(result).asList();
        for (ModelNode loggerName : loggerNames) {
            System.out.printf("logger=%s%n", loggerName.asString());
        }
    } else {
        System.err.printf("Failed to get the logger names: %s%n", Operations.getFailureDescription(result).asString());
    }
}
```

If you want the full description you could use the `read-children-resource` operation instead.

Also the WildFly documentation has a section on [using the ModelControllerClient](http://docs.wildfly.org/15/Admin_Guide.html#working-with-a-modelcontrollerclient) and the [ModelNode and ModelType](http://docs.wildfly.org/15/Admin_Guide.html#modelnode-and-modeltype) API's.